# change line in php file

Tags: php, file, variables

for example I have this php file:

```
{
$data= 'anydata';

$age = '33';

$site ='mysite';

$name = 'anyname'

}
```

**Question:** How I can change the strings with php ?

Comment: remove space from button vlaue. <input type button name="submit" value="  Submit"/>. there is space in value of submit button. it should remove and try it.

Comment: i havent given any value   <button id="fotobut" class="buttoni butnbig" name="submit"> SEND </button>

Comment: can you share your code ... ?

Comment: it is long code and has another problems also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets, read a single line, from the Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

fwrite, from Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

unlink, from Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

rename, from Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

chmod, from Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

```
1. Open file1 (in file), file2 (outfile)
2. use fgets reading single lines (the next line) from file1
3. need to modify that string? do so.
4. use fwrite to write string to file2 (just that line)
5. loop back to 2 when not end-of-file (eof) of file1
6. close file1 and file2
7. unlink (delete) file1
8. rename file2 to file1 name
9. chmod accordingly
```

Comment: you shouldn't use ticks for numbers... use just `$age = 33` and so on.

Comment: i am with you. working off OP code @RaphaelMüller

Comment: yes I know it. it is just example. I would like to know how I can change that strings with php (without opening the file on the server) ?

Comment: a SESSION variable or a reference to an OOP Class object, gets modified  passing values with a $_POST['age'] ?

Comment: I think what you are asking is related to previous versions of your question as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31877367/revisions).

Comment: I think you didnt understand me. I know that must open the file (fopen($file)), then with some code do change to the string of the variable. for example change $age = 33 to $age =22 and etc

Comment: ok so PHP File I/O is the question (I think)

Comment: ok, so that php file, say fred.php, has just that in the above question, and you want to change, say site, to 'ibm.com'. And you want to do it how, thru a form submit with POST variables or something ?

Comment: ok, how flexible do you want it to be? you need to show more details, versus someone answering it, then you want multiple post pairs (variable and value)

Comment: there is rarely an "of course" question on the stack :>  If this was one, it would have been answered Aug7

Comment: I just want to know how to edit(change) the strings with php.

Comment: There ya go Cavid, modified answer. By the way, the word `just` seldom  applies to programming :> Get every row from code table: `select * from myCodeTable` ... now that qualifies for `just`, but not my answer

Comment: are you joking ? this is not mysql. I know how to change rows in mysql. but I dont know how to change lines (with variables, strings) of php file. this is the problem

Comment: oh, you have given an answer, thanks. I will try it

Comment: sadly this is what one has to do in `sequential` file reads versus `random` access file I/O, no different in C, Ruby, you name it. In `random` file I/O with record structures say 512 bytes, you can jump to page or record 123, modify, and close. But there is no structure to your file as such and falls into the `sequential` file category.

Comment: A useful function to write would be one that receives path to file, variable name, and new value. Re-usable. Good for small little conf / text files. The caveat is that it is doing it top to bottom (so for 3 changes, 3 calls, 3 total re-writes)

Comment: I want it for configuration file

Comment: good. for a second there (as you said php file), I thought you wanted your code to modify the code.

Comment: the file will also need chmod 666 I think

Comment: answer modified to reflect that with an added link