# mysql while loop's the last value

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

for example I have this while loop and gives 4 values:

```
while($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $get['anything'];
  echo '<div class="seperatorrrr"></div>';
}
```

**Question**: I dont't want class separator to be shown after the last $get['anything'] value. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$iii=1;
while($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($iii!=1) {
    echo '<div class="seperatorrrr"></div>';
  }
  echo $get['anything'];
  $iii=$iii+1;
}
```

Comment: iii or $i ? or $iii ?

Comment: sorry, thought this was java. $iii php. My head was still in my last answer somewhere else

Comment: think that it must be $i , php doesn't understand just iii

Comment: i modified answer. re-tagged question as `php`

Comment: finally it worked, thank you very much. Yesterday night I tried it with counting all rows but it didn' work: $i = 1; $i++ ; $num = mysql_num_row($results); if ($numresults > 1 && $i < $numresults) echo 'div class="seperator"></div>';

Comment: no problem. please mark answer as helpful or check marked answered so others know. good luck

Comment: yes, to the left of the answer block there is an upvote, downvote (on top and below of the number 0), and when you like an Answer of your choosing, you click on the check mark. That way other users are at least clued in. You can change your choice too later.

Comment: I marked it but couldn't do upvote because of my low reputation, sorry.

Comment: no problem. thx. if you get better answers, just vote them as the Accepted Answer by the green checkmark

Comment: I have another question, but nobody answred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877367/change-line-in-php-file